# Разбить большой xml на несколько маленьких при помощи C#

Tags: c#

есть xml документ следубщего вида:

```
<nsiOrganization>
<oos:regNumber></oos:regNumber>
<oos:shortName></oos:shortName>
<oos:fullName></oos:fullName>
<oos:factualAddress>
<oos:OKATO></oos:OKATO>
<oos:addressLine></oos:addressLine>
<oos:building></oos:building>
<oos:country>
<oos:countryCode></oos:countryCode>
<oos:countryFullName></oos:countryFullName>
</oos:country>
 ...
 ...
 ...
 ...
 ...
</nsiOrganization>
<nsiOrganization>
 ...
 ...
 ...
 ...
 ...
</nsiOrganization>
 ...
 ...
 ...
 ...
 ...
```

как каждый `<nsiOrganization>` разбить по разным xml документам?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Загружаем xml файл
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("C:/myXml.xml");

// делим на части
XElement[] xmls = xDoc.Root.Elements().ToArray(); 

for (int i = 0; i < xmls.Length; i++)
{
    // Записываем каждый элемент в разные файлы
    using (var file = File.CreateText(string.Format("xml{0}.xml", i + 1)))
    {
        //xmls[i] - содержит <nsiOrganization>
        file.Write(xmls[i].ToString());
    }
```

Comment: в `xmls[i]` не понятно что. не отдельные `<nsiOrganization>`  а все подряд и как попало....(

Answer (score 1):

Получилось сделать как-то так...

```
for (int j = 0; j < xmlFilesInFolder.Count; j++)
{
    export exp = new export();
    string usfile = @"C:\Temp\xml\Organization\" + xmlFilesInFolder[j];
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(usfile, FileMode.Open))
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(export));
        exp = (export)xs.Deserialize(stream);
        for (int b = 0; b < ((exportNsiOrganizationList)exp.Items[0]).nsiOrganization.Length; b++)
        {
            Object myOrgan = ((exportNsiOrganizationList)exp.Items[0]).nsiOrganization[b];
            XmlSerializer xss = new XmlSerializer(typeof(zfcs_nsiOrganizationType));
            Stream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\xml\parsxml\_" + filesInFtp[i] + "org_" + (b + 1) + ".xml", FileMode.Create);
            XmlWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8);
            xss.Serialize(writer, myOrgan);
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

можно через регулярные выражения попробовать. Правда там скорее методом проб и ошибок получится, но алгоритм примерно следующий 
1) считываете xml в строку 
2) составляете выражение вида типа

```
"<nsiOrganization>(.|\W)+</nsiOrganization>"
```

3) у вас получится массив типа match, который вы можете записать в разные xml
Опять же повторюсь там есть куча нюансов, например выражение может взять первый  и самый последний , подходит же по идее? )
Так что это нужно будет учесть.

P.S. не знаю сработает ли, но можно попробовать

```
"<nsiOrganization>[^(<nsiOrganization>)]+</nsiOrganization>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете всю обработку сделать в потоках, соответствено направля выходные потоки в файл.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<String> XmlList = new List<String>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String xml =
@"<array>
<nsiOrganization>value1</nsiOrganization>
<nsiOrganization>value2</nsiOrganization>
</array>";

            using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                processXml(stringReader);
            }

            foreach(String s in XmlList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        static void processXml(TextReader textReader)
        {
            using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader))
            {
                xmlReader.MoveToContent();
                xmlReader.ReadStartElement("array");

                while (xmlReader.EOF == false)
                {
                    if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element &&
                        // xmlReader.NamespaceURI == "" &&
                        xmlReader.LocalName == "nsiOrganization")
                    {
                        using (XmlReader elementReader = xmlReader.ReadSubtree())
                        {
                            WriteElement(elementReader);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        xmlReader.Skip();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static void WriteElement(XmlReader xmlReader)
        {
            xmlReader.MoveToContent();

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder))
            {
                xmlWriter.WriteNode(xmlReader, true);
            }

            XmlList.Add(stringBuilder.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
var i = 0;
foreach(XElement el in doc.Elements(XName.Get("nsiOrganization")))
{
     var file = File.CreateText($"путь{i}.xml");
     file.Write(el.ToString());
     i++;
}
```

Comment: ну почти, я бы только сохранял не в  голый XEelement, а в XDocument с копированием деклараций для самостоятельного использования. судя по префиксам у элементов, там еще и схема должна быть по идее, ссылку на которую тоже не грех взять из оригинального документа